# Add reference adds wrong reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies

I'm working on a SL app that needs to reference System.Xml.dll.  So I "Add Reference..." in the project and browse to a common dll folder into which I've copied the silverlight 4.0 version of th System.Xml.dll.

The problem is that the reference gets added as pointing to the

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll

version, which then leads me (I think) to getting "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" when attempting to run the app.  The assemblyBinding in web.config doesn't look to be redirecting and I've attempted setting the project's reference path but still no luck.

Any better ideas?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Adding hint path manually (XML editor) to the reference in the csproj file did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this seems to keep getting viewed I'll officially add the answer:

Adding hint path manually (XML editor) to the reference in the csproj file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the Reference DLL properties and the path was completely wrong, nothing like anything I'd expect it to be, like some random location which just happened to have a very old version of the dll in it. I deleted the file and my DLL hell was over.